# appwidget landscape scalling problems

Tags: android, widget

I am testing my widget under different configs and devices.
It looks good in portrait mode in all devices that ive tried(160dp,240dp...etc)

However,
in landscape mode i had a problem. The last line of text was getting slightly clipped, so i created layout-land and customized for landscape.

all seemed to be ok, until i tested on 160dp emulator: The last line of text is gone completely! (For text size I am using dip units.)

How do you guys approach this problems? I mean, in 240dp device it looks fine, and on the 160dp the last line is totally clipped.

thank you.